# Ĉu "ŝia edzino", aŭ "sia edzino?

Tags: translation, word-choice

Duolingo tradukas "Sophia and her wife" al "Sofia kaj ŝia edzino". Kial oni devas ne uzi "sia" en tiu ĉi frazo, anstataŭ la pronomo "ŝia"?

Comment: Kion signifu la "➡️" en via demando?

Comment: @das-g mi uzas tion por esprimi "bonvole atentu mian demandon"!

Comment: Mi nun forigis ĝin. Ĝi ne helpis kompreni la demandon.

Comment: @das-g mi bedaŭras!

Comment: Ne zorgu. :-) Ĉe Stack Exchange estas normale, ke oni ŝanĝas (kaj espereble plibonigas) la demandojn kaj respondojn de aliaj.

Answer (score 4):

*Si* [ne povas esti parto de subjekto](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/pronomoj/si/simplaj_frazoj.html#i-f6s). En [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/index.html) oni klarigas tion jene:

> Ne diru do: *Karlo kaj sia frato promenas en la parko.*
>
> Se oni dirus
>   tian frazon, oni verŝajne intencus, ke sia reprezentu Karlon, sed la
>   subjekto ja ne estas Karlo, sed *Karlo kaj sia frato*.
>
> Diru: Karlo kaj
>   lia frato promenas en la parko.

Comment: Dankon Sinjoro Trápani. Do, ĉu "sia" nur povas esti objekto de la frazo?

Comment: La pronomo _si_ povas aperi kiel komplemento, objekto, ... sed kiel subjekto. Ekzemplo: _La hundo ludas per sia pilko_.

Comment: Okej, dankon denove!

Comment: @Eduardo Trápani: Ĉu vi celis diri "sed NE kiel subjekto"?

Comment: @Vidamuzo, jes, mankis la "NE". Lla respondo tion klarigas pli bone, ĉar _si_ povas esti nek subjekto nek parto de subjekto. Dankon (mi ne povas korekti komenton tamen).

Answer (score 2):

Temas pri limigoj en kelkaj lingvoj, ekz. en la angla. Se temas pri la subjekto de la frazo, oni povas diri:

- Sofia kaj ŝia edzino...

(de) *Sofia und ihre Frau* / (sv) *Sofia och hennes hustru* / (fi) *Sofia ja hänen vaimonsa* / (en) *Sofia and her wife*

La subjekto estas la tuta esprimo. Temas pri Sofia kaj edzino de Sofia.

- Sofia kun sia edzino...

(de) *Sofia mit seiner Frau* / (sv) *Sofia med sin hustru* / (fi) *Sofia vaimoineen* / (en) *Sofia with her wife*

La subjekto estas nur Sofia kaj la kun-parto estas komplemento al la subjekto. Temas pri Sofia kaj edzino de Sofia.

- Sofia kun ŝia edzino...

(de) *Sofia mit ihrer Frau* / (sv) *Sofia med hennes hustru* / (fi) *Sofia ja tämän vaimo* / (en) *Sofia and her wife*

La subjekto estas nur Sofia kaj la kun-parto estas komplemento al la subjekto. Temas pri Sofia kaj edzino de iu alia persono, kiun oni konas aŭ per la kunteksto aŭ oni menciis tiun personon antaŭe.

Notu, ke oni ne povas diri "Sofia kaj sia edzino...", ĉar tiuokaze oni ne scias, pri kies edzino temas. La esprimo estas erara.

---

Kiel vi vidas, la angla konas nur "her wife", sed en la germana, sveda kaj finna (certe ankaŭ en aliaj lingvoj) oni povas esprimi la saman distingon kiel en Esperanto.

Comment: Sinjoro Metsäkallas, mi nek estas Germano, nek povas paroli la Germanan!

Comment: Dankon por redakti vian respondon! Vi priskribis pri la esprimoj "kaj ŝia", "kun sia" kaj "kun ŝia"; sed verŝajne forgesis priskribi la kvaran ekzemplon, pri kio mi ĉefe demandis, kio estas "kaj sia". De via respondo, ŝajnas al mi ke oni povas diri la frazon uzante "Sofia kaj sia edzino" kiel la subjekto de la frazo, ĉu?

Comment: @Qàtrè, aliaj jam respondis, ke "Sofia kaj sia edzino" estas erara esprimo. Kaj mi komencis per "Oni povas diri". Ĉiuokaze mi aldonis klarigon.

Comment: “Sofia kaj sia edzino” ne estas erara se ĝi ne troviĝas en la subjekto de la frazo. Vidu mian respondon.

Comment: @NeilRoberts, mi tuttempe supozis, ke temas pri la subjekto, ĉar en Duolingo la esprimo estas subjekto. Bone mi aldonis noton.

Comment: Dankon Sinjor' Roberts!

Answer (score 1):

*Si* referencas al la subjekto de la frazo. Via ekzemplo ne estas tuta frazo, do ni ne povas scii en kiu rolo estas tiu frazparto. Ekzemple se la tuta frazo estas:

> Sofia kaj ŝia edzino iris al la superbazaro.

Tiuokaze, la subjekto estas Sofia kaj ŝia edzino. Se oni dirus *sia* anstataŭ *ŝia*, tiam la *sia* ankaŭ referencus al Sofia kaj sia edzino. Do estus kvazaŭ diri:

> Sofia kaj la edzino de (Sofia kaj la edzino de (Sofia kaj la edzino de Sofia [… ktp kun senlima ripetado])) iris al la superbazaro.

Tiu frazo kompreneble ne havas sencon.

Aliflanke, via frazo eblus se la frazparto estus en alia kunteksto. Ekzemple:

> Maria renkontiĝis kun Sofia kaj sia edzino.

Tiuokaze la subjekto estas Maria kaj la edzino estas la edzino de Maria. Tio povus esti ebla traduko de “Sophie and her wife”. Notu ke tiuokaze la angla frazo estus ambigua kaj ni ne nepre scias kies edzino ŝi estas.

Comment: Dankon pro via respondo, Sinjoro Roberts. Mi pardonpetas, ĉar mi atingis tiun ĉi demandon tiam kiam mi praktikis Esperanton uzinte Duolingo, do mi nur skribis la parton "Sofia kaj sia edzino" pri tio mi demandis, kaj forgesis skribi reston de la frazo. Laŭ via respondo, mi supozas ke "ŝia" signifas "her", tamen "sia" signifas "herself", kompare al l'angla. Ĉu mia supozo estas ĝusta?

Comment: Hm, mi supozas ke “ŝia” signifas “her” en frazo kiel “her bicycle is new”. Tamen ankaŭ “sia” povus signifi “her” en frazo kiel “ŝi parolis pri sia biciklo”. Oni povus kompreni “sia” kiel “herself’s” or “himself’s”, krom ke oni ne diras tion en la angla kaj oni simple ĉiam diras “his” or “her”, sendepende ĉu la posedanto referencas la aganton de la frazo.

Comment: Okej, denove dankon!